# MATLAB unable to find the file written by a Python script

Tags: python, matlab, file

Basically, I have  MATLAB code that calls a python code to run. The Python code saves a text file that is later called in the MATLAB code. For some reason, the text file isn't found. Although all the paths seem to match up so not sure what's going on. Why is it not saving?

**The error is shown at the bottom**

This is my MATLAB code:

```matlab
%compute compliance

clear all
close all
n=10;
i=1;
j=1;
X = lhsdesign(n,8);

while i<=n
     i
    dv=X(i,:);
    C=compute_compliance([dv i])
      
    if C<3000
        comp(i)=C;
        i=i+1;
    else
        X(i,:)=rand(1,8);
        badDesign(j,:)=dv;
        badComp(j)=C;
        j=j+1;
    end
 end

function c= compute_compliance(dv)
k=dv(9);
global comp
% [~,output] = dos(strcat(['python cgan_gen.py ']));
[~,output] = dos(strcat(['python C:/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/cgan_gen_input.py ',num2str(dv(1)),' ',num2str(dv(2)),' ',num2str(dv(3)),' '...
    ,num2str(dv(4)),' ',num2str(dv(5)),' ',num2str(dv(6)),' ',num2str(dv(7)),' ',num2str(dv(8)),' ',num2str(k)]));

m = readmatrix('C:/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/top_opt/top.txt');
x=m;
%colormap(gray); imagesc(-x); axis equal; axis tight; axis off;pause(1e-6);
%figure;imshow(x);
nelx=128;
nely=64;
penal=3;
rmin=1.5;
ft=1;
Emin = 1e-9;
E0 = 1;


c=comp_gen(nelx,nely,volfrac,penal,rmin,x);
end
```

And this is the Python file called above (`cgan_gen_input.py`):

```py
import sys
import pdb
#from PIL import Image
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np


lat_noise=np.random.rand(1,8)

lat_noise[0,0]=float(sys.argv[1])
lat_noise[0,1]=float(sys.argv[2])
lat_noise[0,2]=float(sys.argv[3])
lat_noise[0,3]=float(sys.argv[4])
lat_noise[0,4]=float(sys.argv[5])
lat_noise[0,5]=float(sys.argv[6])
lat_noise[0,6]=float(sys.argv[7])
lat_noise[0,7]=float(sys.argv[8])
epoch=float(sys.argv[9]);
#epoch=0

lat_noise.shape
import os
import matplotlib as mpl

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
    mpl.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



from tensorflow import keras


from keras.models import Sequential, Model


# Input shape
img_rows = 64
img_cols = 128
channels = 1
img_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, channels)
latent_dim = 8
input_dim = (latent_dim)


generator = keras.models.load_model(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\UCSDproject\cGANgen_vf8lat_SinglePhys_2.h5',compile=False)
r, c = 1, 1
#lat_noise = np.random.rand(r * c, latent_dim)
vf_noise = np.random.rand(r*c,1)
# Rescale -1 to 1
lat_noise = 2.0*lat_noise - 1
vf_noise = 0.4*vf_noise + 0.2
vf_noise = np.repeat(vf_noise,latent_dim,axis=1)

gen_imgs = generator.predict([lat_noise,vf_noise])
print(gen_imgs)
# Rescale images 0 - 1
gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5
gen_imgs2 =np.squeeze(gen_imgs)
np.savetxt('top_opt/top.txt', gen_imgs2, fmt="%f")
#        pdb.set_trace()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
cnt = 0
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        axs.imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray_r')
        axs.axis('off')
        cnt += 1
#        pdb.set_trace()
#        fig.savefig("/work/05268/csharpe/stampede2/images/cGAN_v3_%d.png" % epoch)
#        fig.savefig('images/1000_1000_100/cGAN_vf8lat_alldata_%d.png' % epoch)
fig.savefig(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\UCSDproject\cGAN_vf8lat_SinglePhys_%d.png' % epoch)
plt.close()
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error below? Looks like all my paths match up. So, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Am I missing something?

```
Error using readmatrix (line 157)
Unable to find or open 'C:/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/top_opt/top.txt'. Check the path and filename or file
permissions.
```

Comment: Try to understand the error.. It says that you don't have permission. Check for the file permission or try to make copy at some other folder and try to access it from there

Comment: But the thing is that I'm creating that file in python-- so why wouldn't I have permission/access to it?

Comment: When you launch Python, it's current directory is the same one as in MATLAB (I believe). In any case, it is not 'C:/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/' just because that is the directory where the Python script lives. You should use an absolute path within your Python script to write this file.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the response! Could you explain what you mean by "an absolute path within your python script"? Thanks!

Comment: In Python you do `np.savetxt('top_opt/top.txt',...)`, in MATLAB you do `readmatrix('C:/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/top_opt/top.txt')`. These are not the same path. Make them the same path.